# puppeteer wrong request.postData()

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

When i try to get postData in request interception from xhr request with hex data i recieve wrong results. I send 4 bytes, and want to recieve that 4 bytes. In php i get this 4 bytes by file_get_contents("php://input") properly, but in puppeteer i recieve 8 bytes. Any one knows how to get raw request post data?

I have html page on server. with that code:

```
<script>
    var bytesToSend = [0xac, 0xed, 0x00, 0x05];
    bytesArray = new Uint8Array(bytesToSend);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://testsite.loc/tests/testserialized.php', false);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
    xhr.send(bytesArray);
</script>
```

"testsite.loc/tests/testserialized.php" - php page to check post data

and node.js puppeteer script. I open my html page in puppeteer with xhr request and intercept requests and try to get post data
this is part of code in node.js

```
page.on('request',async request =>{
    let text = request.postData();
    const fs = require('fs');
    let filename= __dirname + '/../tests/testserialize.txt';
    fs.writeFile(filename, text, function(err) {
        if(err) {
             return console.log(err);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I (or someone will) gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!

Comment: Your backend is php?

Comment: My backend is node.js, php is just for compare results with puppeteer. I tried to improve text and code of problem, problem in puppeteer with request.getPost() function answer.